# PostgreSQL is not recognizing column

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias

My query is below, but for some reason PostgreSQL is not recognizing the row. Let me know what is wrong here. I am using PgAdmin 4 also.

QUERY:

```
SELECT date_part('year',end_of_quarter) as yr,industry,sum(gdp) as totalgdp FROM 
(SELECT * FROM income where industry IN ('Mining','Construction','Utilities')) as MCU
GROUP BY yr,industry
HAVING yr = 2013
ORDER BY totalgdp desc;
```

RESULT:

```
ERROR:  column "yr" does not exist
LINE 4: having yr = 2013
               ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 196
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HAVING` cannot use the alias of an expression. You can `HAVING date_part('year', end_of_quarter) = 2013` instead.